# Define a unique key by EF code first

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, unique-key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unique key with EF code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701608/unique-key-with-ef-code-first)

How can I define a unique key by EF code first. this is my model:

```
public class Users {   
  ...
  public string Username { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

I want to make Username as a unique key.

Answer (score -3):

By putting a key attribute

```
public class Users {   
  ...
  [Key]
  public string Username { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

Comment: It,s not correct, the [key] attribute make username as primary key not unique key.