# Entity Framework 6 Code First Trigger

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework 6 Code First, and would like to create a Trigger.

How do I do this?

The reason I need the trigger is because a user may either edit the database directly or through a program I'm writing, and I need to make sure 2 columns in a table are not both null, and are not both not null.

I've been looking and can't find a way.

Is there any way to specify a trigger using code first?

Comment: Could be useful to add to a lib like [EntityFrameworkExtras](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFrameworkExtras).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Entity Framework has no support for triggers, although you can certainly manually execute a statement that would create a trigger, but you would need to do this after the table was created (if using migrations).

You can use the technique specified by Ladislav in [EF 4.1 code-first adding a trigger to a table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5913581/1743997)

Take note of his warning, however, EF will not be aware of any changes made in the trigger.  If your intent is merely to ensure that 2 columns in a table are not null, you'd be better served with a constraint (constraints are also not supported by EF, but you can add them manually).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Normally I would use a constraint, but, (I didn't mention) I'm planning to use MySQL as well, and MySQL has no support for constraints to my knowledge.

Comment: Does the `[Required]` attribute satisfy the not null constraint?

Comment: @Gusdor - the problem is that he needs to ensure both columns are not null at the same time, while simultaneously allowing either to be null.  The [Required] attribute would not do that.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Understood.

Answer (score 13):

Check out my library [EntityFramework.Triggers](https://github.com/NickStrupat/EntityFramework.Triggers). It works at the Entity Framework layer, so the trigger events won't fire if someone modifies the database directly. The NuGet link is https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Triggers/

Comment: If you'd read the question you would have seen that he wanted a trigger on the database as the database can be modified directly. Your `triggers` aren't really triggers at all, just events on entities currently tracked by a DbContext. Considering the life of a DbContext is supposed to be quite short I don't really see the point.

Comment: A good library, but not quite what I'm after. If I open two contexts between two different applications, and trigger events they aren't shared.

Comment: @wonea that functionality is next on the list. I am thinking of adding support for message queues to pass trigger events across instances, applications, even machines.

Answer (score 7):

After you add a migration, open the migration file and create your trigger as shown below

Note: you need to run **update-database** to see the changes in your database.

[image]

Comment: I think it is migrationBuilder.Sql in Entity Framework 7 now.