# entity framework insert into "base" table while inserting record

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using `EF Core 1.0` (although I guess it's generic question for EF).

I have table `Resource`, `Employee` and `Equipment` (`Resource` is like a base table, meaning `Employee` is also `Resource` and `Equipment` is also `Resource`).

So when creating `Employee` record I would like to automatically insert record into `Resource` table.

All tables has `ID` column.

`Resource.ID` is `PK identity`.

`Employee.ID` is `PK (not identity)` - it's `FK` to `Resource.ID`

Is there sexy way of doing it in EF (other than manually adding both records in my code)?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there inheritance between the entities on code level? If so, then you can apply some inheritance managed by EF as it is described [here]|(http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx).

Comment: No - there separate classes in my code. Also I'm using EF core, which supports ATM TPH only.

Comment: TPH is not good for you in this case? However, I have found this when I searched for trigger and EF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943314/entity-framework-6-code-first-trigger

Comment: I think I need to wait for TPC features in EF Core. Thanks anyway!