# How to execute native SQL inside a migration for Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, database-trigger

I would like to define PL/pgSQL function and set trigger for it. I know that `EF` does not work with triggers. But I saw solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56263887/7542937).

Ok, it looks like nice. But It works for old `EF`. What bout `EF Core`? Have it suitable method?

I will show you my code:

```
public partial class CreateTriggrerBeforeInsertToFailedPushes : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        Sql(@"< here is my function text>");
        Sql(@"< here is my trigger text>");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        Sql(@"< here is command for remove the trigger >");

        Sql(@"< here is command for remove the function >");

    }
}
```

What do you think about it? Will it work? Or it is bad idea and there is a better way?

Comment: For EF Core it's the same - just the method is on `MigrationBuilder` rather than `Migration` (similar to other migration command methods), e.g. `migrationBuilder.Sql(…)`

Comment: Now I see! Thank you!