# dataannotations set identity seed value on Primary Key with code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first, data-annotations

ASP.NET MVC3 code first project.

In my class definition how do I set the Identity seed value.

```
  public class Account
  {
    [Key]   
    public int Id { get; set; }
```

What would be the syntax to set the Identity seed to 1000000?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to start the seed at 1000000 or do you want to set the Id for a specific entity?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5974656/968301

Comment: Kane  I want to start the seed at 1000000.  Not sure I follow the second question.  I want the Primary Key ID in the Account table to be seeded with 1000000 when it is created and increment by 1 from there.

Comment: Craig  Not simple huh?  I'll try and take a closer look at that link and its links.  I was hoping for something with dataannotations or fluent API.

Comment: For EF Core Identity Seed notice to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34927619/entity-framework-7-identity-seed/48595581#48595581)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Craig, after looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5974656/968301 it was pretty simple.

Create an intializer

```
public class MyInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyContext> 
{   
  protected override void Seed(MyContext context) 
  {   
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Account', RESEED, 1000000)");
  }  
}
```

Then call from the Application_Start section of the Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  Database.SetInitializer(new MyInitializer());
  AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

  RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
  RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```