# Force EntityFramework to use OUTPUT not SCOPE_IDENTITY to retrieve key value

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework code first to access a set of tables whose key will be set by an int based SEQUENCE in a default constraint.  EF seems to have trouble handling this, it insists on using SCOPE_IDENTITY after an insert to populate integer key fields.

Digging into the code, it looks kind of hard-coded:

http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/SqlGen/DmlSqlGenerator.cs

See the IsValidScopeIdentityColumnType method a little over halfway down the page.  If this method returns true the inserted Key value is retrieved with SCOPE_IDENTITY(), otherwise an OUTPUT clause is generated.  (Guid/uniqueidentifier is the typical use case there).

```
        // make sure it's a primitive type
        if (typeUsage.EdmType.BuiltInTypeKind != BuiltInTypeKind.PrimitiveType)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // check if this is a supported primitive type (compare by name)
        var typeName = typeUsage.EdmType.Name;

        // integer types
        if (typeName == "tinyint"
            || typeName == "smallint"
            ||
            typeName == "int"
            || typeName == "bigint")
        {
            return true;
        }
```

Is there any way to fool this method into returning false for an integral field?  Once I start seeing things like 'EDMType' I'm beyond what I really understand about how the EF mapping really works.  Maybe there's some way to use a user defined type to fool it?  But it's really the configuration on the .NET side that needs some sort of update.

See also the UseGeneratedValuesVariable method in that same file for where this is used...

It's not clear to me why OUTPUT isn't just used across the board here -- maybe performance?

Comment: "It's not clear to me why OUTPUT isn't just used across the board here" -- As noted in the comments in the method of `UseGeneratedValuesVariable`, in the same file you found, OUTPUT doesn't exist for older versions of SQL Server. Also, even with newer versions, I think there are some cases where OUTPUT does not work (related to triggers).

Comment: They actually check the version of SQL in some places...but triggers....always a problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE - ONLY IDENTITY SUPPORTED FOR DB GENERATED PK**

You can create a key column marked as computed, which has a `DataseGeneratedOption.Computed`. (See [DataseGeneratedOption enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

To indicate this you can decorate the column with [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or use the fluent API, in the `OnModelCreating` method of your DbContext, like so:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityType>()
            .Property(c => c.KeyColumn)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)
```

This sample code works perfectly with EF6.1

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<ComputedKey> ComputedKeys { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        // Computed Key:
        modelBuilder.Entity<ComputedKey>()
            .HasKey(c => c.Id)
            .Property(c => c.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
    }
}

public class ComputedKey
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

When you run the app, the table is created correctly.

The problem arises when you try to add the first entity to the entity collection and save changes. You get: `Modifications to tables where a primary key column has property 'StoreGeneratedPattern' set to 'Computed' are not supported. Use 'Identity' pattern instead. Key column: 'Id'. Table: 'CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.ComputedKey'`.

This is a limitation of EF (until 6.1) that only allows to have integer type or GUID as DB generated value for a PK.

**WORKAROUNDS**

**First:**
One would be to use the column generated on the DB as an alternative key.

From EF 6.1 on you can create the AK, decorating the AK column with an attribute like this:

```
[Index("MyIndex", unique: true)]
```

**Second:**
The reason for using a sequence is defining the seed and the increment. If this is what you need you can modify the identity like this:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('SchemaName.TableName', RESEED, 10);
```

This means that the next generated identity value will be 11, and the increment will be 1.

If you need to use a different increment you'd need to drop and re-create the identity column, indicating the seed and increment. But for doing this you also need to drop and create the associated foreingk keys, so that's too hard to implement.

**Third:**
You could use a trigger. Inside the trigger you can use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT tableName ON/OFF`, but then again you can have problems because the `@@identity` will mismatch.

*NOTE: if you need to run custom SQL commands to apply this customizations, you need to implement the Seed method of your db initializer*

**CONCLUSION**

This scenario is only partially supported, so you'd rather find an alternative solution, unless one of the previous work arounds work for you.

**REQUEST THIS FUNCTIONALITY**

if you're interested in this functionality, go to the Entity Framework Feature Suggestions, and vote for this: [Allow using SQL Server 2012 sequence for generating primary key](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2541076-allow-using-sql-server-2012-sequence-for-generatin)

Comment: Key fields cannot have the 'Computed' metadata.  Throws an exception.

Comment: You'll have to discover why **in your particular case** that happens. I have a proof of concept that works perfectly. I've copied the code for you into my answer.

Comment: Added your code to an empty project:  {"Modifications to tables where a primary key column has property 'StoreGeneratedPattern' set to 'Computed' are not supported. Use 'Identity' pattern instead. Key column: 'Id'. Table: 'CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.ComputedKey'."}

Comment: You need to actually try and save one of the entities in order to trigger code that attempts to generate SQL

Comment: I'm using EF 6.1.0 from nuget, if that's relevant to you

Comment: You was absolutley right. I've updated my answer. I don't know if this answer will solve your problem or not, but I think that now that it reflects the reality, you should remove the -1, only to make it useful for other people. I hope my workarounds can help you in some way

Comment: It looks like SEQUENCE backed key fields just won't work with EF.  I'm trying to implement a 'table-per-concrete-type' hierarchy here.  Unless someone else comes up with a better idea, the best solution is probably similar to your second answer here and just use IDENTITY with staggered start values and increments.  And hope that future changes don't ever require more sub-classes than I left as an IDENTITY gap.

Comment: I've added a link to a site where you can vote for the new EF functionalities in which you're interested, particularly in the use of SEQUENCE as Key.