# How to set Identity Seed value in code-first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

We are using Code First with EF-core and I would like to add a column which has an Identity Seed starting at another value other to 1.

Currently we can set it to auto increment via the `EntityTypeBuilder` during migrations using:

```cs
entityBuilder.Property(e => e.PropertyName).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

However I cannot find out how to change the identity seed. Does it still need to be updated like it was with other versions of EF? e.g. writing some custom sql and running this during migration?

[How to seed identity seed value in entity framework code first for several tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28920768/how-to-seed-identity-seed-value-in-entity-framework-code-first-for-several-table)

[How do I set Identity seed on an ID column using Entity Framework 4 code first with SQL Compact 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732102/how-do-i-set-identity-seed-on-an-id-column-using-entity-framework-4-code-first-w)

In EF-core there does not seem to be code for `SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator > override Generate(AlterTableOperation alterTableOperation)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Entity Framework Core Use `Sql` Command in `Up` method:

> Important Part: `migrationBuilder.Sql("DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Payment', RESEED, 1000000)");`

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
using System;

namespace PaymentService.Migrations
{
    public partial class Initial : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Payment",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                          .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Payment", x => x.Id);
            });

            // Below code is for seeding the identity
            migrationBuilder.Sql("DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Payment', RESEED, 1000000)");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(name: "Payment");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

**Update 2020**.

After EF Core 3.0 now you have a **UseIdentityColumn** extension method which can be used for setting the seed and increment values for identity columns.

```
builder.Property(prop => prop.Id)
            .UseIdentityColumn(10000000, 1);
```

As per offcial documentation:

> UseIdentityColumn Configures the key property to use the SQL Server IDENTITY feature to generate values for new entities, when targeting SQL Server. This method sets the property to be OnAdd.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverpropertybuilderextensions.useidentitycolumn?view=efcore-3.0)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must write the required SQL statement to set the seed, and then use the Sql method in the migration.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any documentation for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL instead of SQL Server, add the following in place of `"migrationBuilder.Sql("DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Payment', RESEED, 1000000)");"` from the first answer:

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("use db_name; ALTER TABLE Clients AUTO_INCREMENT = start_value;");
```

Answer (score -1):

In **migrationBuilder.CreateTable** I have set  Id to Identity column

```css
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "tblEmployees",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false).Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),//for set identity column
                    EmployeeCode = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 100, nullable: false)
 },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_tblEmployees", x => x.Id);
                });
```

It worked for me

Comment: Doesn't answer the question "However I cannot find out how to change the identity seed." I think other answers address this question sufficiently, no need to add anything to it now.