# Fluent API database auto key generation start with 5 or more digit

Tags: entity-framework-core

How to tell Fluent API auto-increment to start with more than 5 digits key generation?

I mean `.ValueGeneratedOnAdd();` will start with 1 but I want start with 50000 and then auto-increment

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34927619/how-to-set-identity-seed-value-in-code-first) help ?

Comment: Use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64101019/5202563) from the post marked as duplicate instead of the accepted which is outdated.