# setting primary key identity using code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

How can I set the starting value for an identity primary key when using the mvc 5 code first approach?

Recently I tried using

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DataGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

but this automatically starts the values off at 1 whereas I want to set my own starting value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [EF Code First - how to set identity seed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974554/ef-code-first-how-to-set-identity-seed)

Comment: try look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701608/unique-key-with-ef-code-first/5701702#5701702 and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974554/ef-code-first-how-to-set-identity-seed