# Specifying Sequence start value in identity columns

Tags: entity-framework-core, npgsql

Is it possible to specify the sequence start value when using identity columns ?

Combine this

```
        modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>("OrderNumbers", schema: "shared")
            .StartsAt(1000);
```

with this

```
modelBuilder.ForNpgsqlUseIdentityColumns();
```

in code.

Comment: No, identity and sequence objects have different behavior.

Comment: True, though it is possible to specify the start value of an identity. Perhaps there's a code first syntax for it?

Comment: No, As I know there is no way to set the seed or increment value for identity with code first, You need to execute raw SQL for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974554/ef-code-first-how-to-set-identity-seed

Answer (score 0):

This is supported by PostgreSQL but hasn't yet been implemented in the Npgsql EF Core provider. It is being tracked by https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/819 (upvote if you're interested).