# EF Code First - Set or infulence the foreign key reference names

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I have read many posts about how to specify the foreign key name in relationships, no problems there.  What I would like to know though, is there a way to change how the primary keys and relationships are named?

For instance, you have a User table with UserId as the primary key.  The primary key is called **PK_*User*_1788CC4C07020F21** (or something like that) by the EF code first database generation.  Or you have a reference from your User table to your UserVersion table and that is called **UserVersion_User** by EF.  I would like to have the primary key called something like **PK_User** and the foreign reference something like **FK_UserVersion_User**.

Is there a way to do this?  Some convention override or actually being able to specify the text?

Thanks.

**Update:**
Based on the answer and link bellow I did the following in my Seed method.  It's kinda brute force, but I recon that it can be refined, especially if you create the fluent entity type configuration files etc with a generator. The same could be done for the foreign key reference names.

```
    protected override void Seed(TodoDataContext context)
    {
        FixIndexes(context, "User");
        FixIndexes(context, "UserStats");
        FixIndexes(context, "UserRole");
        FixIndexes(context, "UserVersion");
        FixIndexes(context, "UserUserRoleVersion");
    }

    private void FixIndexes(TodoDataContext context, string tableName)
    {
        const string renamePrimaryKeySql = @"
            DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(128)
            DECLARE @IndexName NVARCHAR(128)
            DECLARE @OldName NVARCHAR(128)
            DECLARE @NewName NVARCHAR(128)
            SELECT  @TableName = '{0}'

            SELECT  @IndexName = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK ,INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE C
            WHERE   pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
              AND   CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
              AND   C.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME
              AND   C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME

            SELECT  @OldName = @TableName + '.' + @IndexName
            SELECT  @NewName = 'PK_' + @TableName

            exec sp_rename @OldName, @NewName, 'INDEX'";

        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(string.Format(renamePrimaryKeySql, tableName));
```

Comment: Hi Tyrel,  just wanted to say thank you for the update; FixIndexes was exactly what I was looking for and it works perfectly! :))

Comment: There is a bug related to sp_rename.  Basically, we also have to update the is_system_named column in the sys.key_constraints column so that if\when we generate creation scripts in SSMS for example, the primary key names will also be included.  See this: http://davidbrycehoward.com/archive/2011/01/naming-and-renaming-database-constraints/.  This bug should be fixed in the next version of SQL Server, code-named "Denali".

Comment: To fix the is_system_name issue, I had to do two things: 1. deploy the database to sql server 2008 r2 and 2. pass 'OBJECT' instead of 'INDEX' to sp_rename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way to change these names unless you manually drop them in [custom initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701608/unique-key-with-ef-code-first/5701702#5701702) and create them again. EF doesn't have pluggable conventions so you cannot override them.

Comment: Sadly, that's what I was expecting.  Thanks for your reply.