# Creating BiDirectional One - One relationship in Entity Framework 4.1 Code First

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, code-first, relationships

I want to created Bi-Directional One-One relationship between two entities using EF Code First. I have trouble with the following code. What do you think I should do?

```
public class User
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public int ProfileID { get; set; }
    public Profile Profile { get; set; }

}
public class Profile
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int ProfileID { get; set; }
    public string ProfileName { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdateDate { get; set; }

}
```

I want to have both Navigation property and Foreign Key in both the entities.

This gives me error. What can do I in Fluent Mapping API to make this work?

Answer (score 18):

Use this:

```
public class User
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public Profile Profile { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public int ProfileID { get; set; }
    public string ProfileName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

That is the only valid way to build one-to-one relation in EF - PK of the dependent entity must be also FK to principal entity. There is nothing like bidirectional one-to-one relation in EF because it cannot work in EF.

The way how people sometimes overcome this are two one-to-many relations where principal doesn't have navigation collection for dependent entities + manually defined unique keys in the database. That require manual mapping:

```
public class User
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    // one side MUST be nullable otherwise you have bidirectional constraint where each
    // entity demands other side to be inserted first = not possible
    public int? ProfileId { get; set; } 
    public Profile Profile { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    public int ProfileID { get; set; }
    public string ProfileName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

And in mapping you will define:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>
            .HasOptional(u => u.Profile)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.ProfileId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>
            .HasRequired(u => u.User)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.UserId);
```

Now you must define Unique keys in the database - if you are using code first use [custom database initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701608/unique-key-with-ef-code-first/5701702#5701702)r. Be aware that still bidirectional one-to-one is wrong concept because both sides demand unique FK where NULL is still included in unique values so once you insert `User` before `Profile` there mustn't be any other `User` without `Profile`. That probably leads to serializable transaction.

Comment: Ladislav, Now it makes perfect sense... I understand how the relationships are made... although I agree it should've been supported in a better way that creating unique key manually...

Comment: why WithMany if this is one-to-one relation?

Comment: @angel: It is a workaround to overcome limitations of EF - second part of the answer is cheating EF by telling it that there are two one-to-many relations instead of mapping one-to-one directly. One-to-one is ensured on database level by putting unique key constraints on foreign key columns.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka what about an update of the foreign key in User table? Is it possible? I mean changing the profile of a user (although it doesn't make sense in this example and makes sense in another examples)