# Unique Constraint with Entity Framework using Code First Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-4, code-first

I am doing entity framework (v 5) code first migrations, on an MVC 4 application. I would like to add a unique constraint at the database level.

I know this can be done when creating the table, but I already have a table.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621

I have tried the following, marked as answer answer: [Unique constraint with EFCodeFirst and SqlCe4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727738/unique-constraint-with-efcodefirst-and-sqlce4)

My database context differes slightly, I supply the connection name is as follows

```
public AppDatabaseContext() : base("MyConnectionDBContext")
```

When I use the Package Management Console to update the database, the overridden seed method is not called:

```
protected override void Seed(AppDatabaseContext context)
```

I have also tried the following: http://romiller.com/2010/07/31/ef-ctp4-tips-tricks-running-additional-ddl/

I did not use a nested class, this is because it seemed as if I had to registere the initializer via the app.config. I could not get it working while initializing it in code. The InitializeDatabase is called, but the following condition is never true:

```
(!context.Database.Exists() || !context.Database.ModelMatchesDatabase())
```

This is because this happens after the migrations have been run...

I also tried this at one stage: [Unique Constraint in Entity Framework Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413084/unique-constraint-in-entity-framework-code-first), it was the same problem as before, this condition was never returning true.

Ideally, I would like to include some standard SQL in my migration file. Is there a way to do that? If not, where can I see how to achieve this with using code first migrations?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Is there any reason why I can't use the SQL function?

```
 public override void Up()
 {
        AddColumn("Posts", "Abstract", c => c.String());

        Sql("UPDATE Posts SET Abstract = LEFT(Content, 100) WHERE Abstract IS NULL");
 }
```

Obviously using the correct SQL...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

With code first migrations, I've just used this in the `Up()` method to add a unique index on a single column:

```
CreateIndex(table: "Organisations", 
            column: "Name", 
            unique: true, // unique index
            name: "MyIndex");
```

...and then in the `Down()` method:

```
DropIndex(table: "Organisations", 
          name: "MyIndex");
```

Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 9):

Since EF 6.1 you can now do this in your model with either

an attribute

```
 [Index("IX_UniqueName", IsUnique = true)]
 public string Name {get;set;}
```

or fluent

```
Property(s => s.Name).HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName,
    new IndexAnnotation(
        new IndexAttribute("IX_UniqueName") { IsUnique = true }));
```

The fluent method isn't perfect as its crazy verbose IMO but at least its possible now.

More deets on Arthur Vickers blog http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2014/02/15/ef-6-1-creating-indexes-with-indexattribute/

Answer (score 6):

You can just scaffold a new migration using the `Add-Migration` command from your package manager console. Once the empty migration is created, in the `Up` method, you can use the `CreateIndex` method of the `DbMigration` class to create your new index. It would look like something like this:

```
CreateIndex("dbo.Accounts", "AccessKey", unique: true);
```

Comment: How would you do this if you're using Automatic Migrations?

Comment: @MikeCole I know your comment is super old, but see my new answer as this is now possible