# How to add unique non primary-key field to entity using Entity Framework 4.1?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, key, unique

We are using Entity Framework 4.1 Code first.

We've got user entity with primary key set to `UserId` and need `UserLogin` to be unique. How can it be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unique key with EF code first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701608/unique-key-with-ef-code-first)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Entity Framework does not support Unique constraints. You can create them using a SQL Query to generate unique constrains when initializing the database. Write your custom initializer for the model and execute SQL command to generate  constrain.

Edit

Now (EF 6.1 onwards )you can easily have unique constrains ,

```
[Index("UserLoginIndex", IsUnique = True)]
public string UserLogin { get; set; }
```

Comment: As of EF 6.1 the `[Index(IsUnique = true)]` data annotation is available

Comment: Yeah it's not released yet though.

Comment: The [nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/) package was released on 3/17/14..

Answer (score 2):

Check out the unique constraints, I think that's what you're looking for?

http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/23/associations-in-ef-code-first-ctp5-part-3-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx

Comment: That is answer pointing to non existing API. No EF version supports this yet.

Comment: New link supported by CTP5 added, that any use?