# How can I force my DB Initializer to create a table for an ENUM?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have the following code for the Model, and also for the initializer.
However the status property is created as an INT and I would like it to be a foreign key to a STATUS Table.

Is this possible, or I need to remove the ENUM and create a class?

```
 public class Applicant
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]      
        public int ApplicantID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")] 
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage="Name should not be longer than 20 characters.")]
        [Display(Name = "First and LastName")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Telephone number is required")] 
        [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Telephone should not be longer than 20 characters.")]
        [Display(Name = "Telephone Number")]
        public string telephone { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Skype username is required")] 
        [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Skype user should not be longer than 20 characters.")]
        [Display(Name = "Skype Username")]
        public string skypeuser { get; set; }

        public byte[] photo { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ApplicantPosition> applicantPosition { get; set; }


    }

    public class ApplicantPosition
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("ApplicantID", Order = 0)]
        public int ApplicantID { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column("PositionID", Order = 1)]
        public int PositionID { get; set; }

        public virtual Position Position { get; set; }

        public virtual Applicant Applicant { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Applied date is required")] 
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Date applied")]     
        public DateTime appliedDate { get; set; }

        public int StatusValue { get; set; }

        public Status Status
        {
            get { return (Status)StatusValue; }
            set { StatusValue = (int)value; }
        }

    }


    public class ApplicationPositionHistory
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ApplicationPositionHistoryID { get; set; }

        public ApplicantPosition applicantPosition { get; set; }

        public Status oldStatus { get; set; }

        public Status newStatus { get; set; }

        [StringLength(500, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Commebnts  should not be longer than 500 characters.")]
        [Display(Name = "Comments")]
        public string comments { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Date")]     
        public DateTime dateModified { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Status
    {
        Applied,
        AcceptedByHR,
        AcceptedByTechnicalDepartment,
        InterviewedByHR,
        InterviewedByTechnicalDepartment,
        InterviewedByGeneralManager,
        AcceptedByGeneralManager,
        NotAccepted
    }

public class HRContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Position> Positions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Applicant> Applicants { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicantPosition> ApplicantsPositions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicationPositionHistory> ApplicationsPositionHistory { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Position>().ToTable("Position");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Applicant>().ToTable("Applicant");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicantPosition>().ToTable("ApplicantPosition");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationPositionHistory>().ToTable("ApplicationsPositionHistory");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Position>().Property(c => c.name).IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Applicant>().Property(c => c.name).IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicantPosition>().Property(c => c.appliedDate).IsRequired();

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `Status` to be a table created automatically you must create it a `class`.

Other way is implementing [custom database initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701608/unique-key-with-ef-code-first/5701702#5701702) and manually execute SQL to create table, fill it with data and create referential constraint from related tables.

Btw. Enum is not an entity and if you work with enum you should not model it as a table. [Check constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx) should be used in database to limit values for `Status` column (again you must create constraint manually in custom initializer).

Comment: Ok I will do it, and I will populate the values as well, however is it possible to map the database values with an enum? in case i want to make queries I dont want to query status=1, but status== status.applied for example, do you understand what I meant?

Comment: No EF doesn't support enums yet. The closes solution you can get is [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/05/tip-23-how-to-fake-enums-in-ef-4.aspx).