# Is there any Attribute to Check Repetition in Create new Item with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, attributes

I Have a MVC Project with a Model named Contact, in create view how can I Check if the new value is exist avoid to register it, is there any Attribute to check it Automatically like `[Required]` Validator? something like `[NoRepeated]` ??

Comment: " new value is exist" - where? in your database ?

Comment: yes. i need to avoid duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should make the DB column a unique one. And when duplicates are inserted it will throw an exception . Which you can catch and show to the user as an error.

Comment: hmm, I use EFCodefirst, how can I define UK in overriding OnModelCreating method?

Comment: here you go, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701608/unique-key-with-ef-code-first

Comment: I work with MVC 3 and EF 4 and the code don't recognize ExecuteSqlCommand in context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_Category_Title ON Categories (Title)"); is this about version or otherthing?

Comment: did u execute the exact same query? you need to provide proper table name instead of "Categories" and your column name instead of "Title"

Comment: I know about the query, but the main problem is in context.Database the ExecuteSqlCommand not Exist.??

Comment: Hmm This is all about the version

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing this automatically for you, since you have to query your database. You can do this via Ajax directly from your view and in any case also after the view is posted.

See the following link to get started writing a custom ValidationAttribute which does a similar thing: http://devermind.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/asp-net-mvc-tip-4-client-side-form-validation-made-easy-part-2/