# Using EF code-first while retaining stored procedures

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ef-code-first

I've started building a project using code-first in EF4.0 to build my database. I now wish to create some stored procedures in SQL Server 2008 that will work on the created data tables.

However, since CF drops and recreates the *entire* database, I would lose any stored procedures I create and would have to rebuild them each time - it would be easy to inadvertently lose work this way.

Are there "best practices" here? Of course I could always lock down the schema now and forget about code first but it's not ideal. Why would EF delete the *entire* DB - is there a way to delete *just* the tables?

Comment: Since EF code-first right now (EF 4.3) doesn't and in the near future (EF 5.0) still won't support stored procedures, I'm afraid there's not a lot you can do. But : you could look into [EF code-first **migrations**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx) to avoid constantly dropping & re-creating your database - instead, you incrementally upgrade it as you need. This will leave your stored procedures intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [custom database initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701608/unique-key-with-ef-code-first/5701702#5701702) which will create your stored procedures every time you recreate database. You can also use [EF migrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx) to build your database incrementally instead of deleting it after each change. `Up` method in the migration can use `Sql` method to create stored procedures.