# EF4 Automatic Check Constraints

Tags: entity-framework-4, check-constraint

How can I specify a Check Constraint in EF4 CodeFirst.

Example: I have a string property for which I can have only specific values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF code first doesn't have any equivalent for check constraints. If you want to have check constraint in the database you can either use custom database initializer and execute custom SQL to alter table and add check constraint (I described similar approach for unique index [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701608/unique-key-with-ef-code-first/5701702#5701702)) or if you are already using EF code first migrations you can add constraint creation to your `Up` method in code based migration.