# Unique key applying on asp.net MVC 5 model property

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have User(name,password) model and Roles model(id,role).Now what I want is mapping model(id,Uid,Rid) between these two models and here Uid,Rid foreign keys also Uid should be unique. How can acheive this. I have done with foreign key and with mapping table but I stuck at unique key applying on Uid.

Can anyone help me in this?
Thanks in advance.

```
 public class Image
 {
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public String Password { get; set; }
}

//User roles class
public class Role
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string Roles { get; set; }
}

//User mapping with roles
public class Rolemapping
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public int Uid { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Uid")]
    public Image User { get; set; }

    public int Rid { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Rid")]
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: just put the 2 models u r talking about

Comment: Ok changed, Please look at the code and help me

Comment: include [key] on top od Uid

Comment: codefirst or db first?

Comment: If I include [Key] at the top of Uid than it is becoming Primary Key but I want to apply foreign key and unique key on Uid!

Comment: FYI Foreign key constraint is being implemented on a primary key if I'm not wrong

Comment: which EF you are using? 6.1?

Comment: answered for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Unique Key in Model Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701608/unique-key-with-ef-code-first)**

Follow the above link to create Unique Key prior to EF 6.1 and

EF 6.1 onwards you can easily have unique constrains ,

`[Index("TitleIndex", IsUnique = true)]`

`public string Title { get; set; }`

Comment: Thanks I am using EF 6.1 and this solution fits my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MYSQL you are likely to get BLOB/TEXT column 'value' used in key specification without a key length so add a key length

```
[Index("TitleIndex", IsUnique = true)]
[MaxLength(15)]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

This will change the field type to varchar as well