# MVC Entity Framework validation to prevent duplicate records

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

Hi i'm new to MVC and EF so this may be a really simple question but what is the best way to prevent the user from trying to enter duplicate records?

I have a simple look up table with one column which is the primary key. I'm creating a maintenance screen so admins can add extra items to the look up list. My controller looks like :

```
public ActionResult Index(string NewRow)
    {
        try
        {
            CaseType t = new CaseType { ID = NewRow };
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                UOW.CaseTypes.Add(t);
                UOW.Save();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
        }
        return View(UOW.CaseTypes.All());
    }
```

Which stops the duplicate records and stops the yellow screen of death but the message displayed is : "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details." which is no good for the users.

I was just wondering if there is a better way to catch the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For show validation error I use something like this:

MainEmail it's property from ViewModel

```
        var mod = ModelState.First(c => c.Key == "MainEmail");  // this
        mod.Value.Errors.Add("Row's shouldn't duplicates.");    // this

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Details");
        }

        return View(client);
```

Error will show's in this field in view:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MainEmail)
    </div>
```

And for future, you must hide your error screen! You need to display a custom error page:

If you use asp-mvc-3, add to web.config such string:

```
  <system.web>
     <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error" />
     ...
```

And users will have /Shared/Error.cshtml page insted of page with exception message (which can show sequrity data).

**ADD**

About unique constraint creation was discussed here
[Unique Constraint in Entity Framework Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413084/unique-constraint-in-entity-framework-code-first)

than you can check about records duplication with your try code.

In my application I use code first and don't add unique constraint because it's lead to low testability. In that case use simple *Find* before saving changes.

First aproach is little bit faster.

Approach two is grow up testability.

Comment: Hmm...my answer not help you?

Comment: excellent thanks, and i was planning on removing the error screen its just in development right now but thanks for the top tip.

Comment: Hi, just got around to messing around with this and while your code is helpfull it does not actually achieve what i was looking for. It seems to just look for a field in the form data and add a validation message. I was looking for was a way to check for duplicates, so for example if i already have case type "22" in the table and at some point a user trys to create another "22" the system should say "sorry thats a duplicate" rather then "bam" yellow screen of death. Just wondered if i should run a "find" on the data first or catch the error which is less strain on the server?

Comment: If you also add unique constraint to the table column in the server, be better if you catch exception (It's more faster).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the inner exception you can do like this,

```
catch (Exception ex)
        {
           while(ex.InnerException!=null){
                 ex=ex.InnerException;
           }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
        }
```

no too sure about the syntax :)