# Defining a field as unique in my entity (but not primary key)

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

I use Entity Code first in my solution. Lets say I already have a primary key in my table (projectID) but I would like another field to be unique (SlugName). How can I achieve this?

Here is my entity:

```
[Key]
public int ProjectID   { get; set; }
public string Name     { get; set; }
public string SlugName { get; set; }
```

Thanks.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413084/unique-constraint-in-entity-framework-code-first