# How to set a field unique in Entity Framework 4.1 code first? No annotation attibrute?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, annotations, ef-code-first

I've been looking for a way to set a field unique , but i' am surprised i can't find anything like annotation on the field. In most of the resource online one have to write `SQL` in an [initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413084/unique-constraint-in-entity-framework-code-first). i was even hoping i could find something like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>().HasKey(p => p.RollNumber);
```

in which `HasKey` could be `HasUnique` or even `HasUniqueKey`

Is it that am not searching with the proper keyword or that annotation feature is simply not available (to my surprise ).

Comment: There is no built in mechanism to configure Unique Keys

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comments:

There was a promising [post on some design considerations regarding unique constraint support](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/03/09/unique-constraints-in-the-entity-framework.aspx) almost a year ago at the Entity Framework Design design blog. However, there is no mention of it in [EF 5.0.0 beta1 pre-release](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/29/ef4-3-1-and-ef5-beta-1-available-on-nuget.aspx).

I can not find any later reference to it on the EF blogs or on the [pre-release forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/threads), neither is there a (public) roadmap so it is hard to tell when or whether this feature will be released.

So, not really an answer to your question, because there is no "how to" yet.