# Unique index per Foreign Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, constraints, code-first

I am looking for a way to perform some slightly more intelligent unique constraints on my EF Code First database table.

I have a two models in play; A Setting and a Tenant.

```
public class Setting
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
}

public class Tenant
{
    ///
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Setting> Settings { get; set; }
    ///
}
```

As you can probably guess, a Setting is linked to it's Tenant by the TenantId property which acts as the foreign key and match the Tenant's Id property.

What I want to achieve is to say that the Setting name must be unique per Tenant. For example, you can have a Setting named "SettingA" under "Tenant01" and a "SettingA" under "Tenant02" (each of which are two separate entities with here own Ids in the table, and can thus have different Values) and this be legal, but not allow for another Setting name "SettingA" to the Tenant's where it already exists.

I can see plenty of ways to just enforce straight uniqueness through the likes of database initialisation and checking when adding etc, but nothing on "conditional uniqueness".

Comment: if I understand well, this looks like a unique constraint on pair [Setting.Name, Setting.TenantId] ?

Comment: I'm nearly 100% confident there is no structure to do this built-in, however you could build your own attribute to handle it. It would be fairly straight forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like an unique constraint on [Setting.Name, Setting.TenantId]

You should have validation rules in the "Code side", to avoid Sql errors on Save, and a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on your db... to be consitent.

**Code side**

This can easily be achieved with a validation lib like FluentValidation, but you could also do this with custom attributes

**Db side**

*With migrations*

In up method :

```
CreateIndex("dbo.Setting", new[]{"TenantId", "Name"}, true, "Setting_UC");
```

In down method :

```
DropIndex("dbo.Setting", "Setting_UC");
```

*Without migrations*

see [Unique Constraint in Entity Framework Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413084/unique-constraint-in-entity-framework-code-first)

Comment: That's a great start for me to be getting on with. Thank you kindly. =)

Comment: Apparently: "Column 'Name' in table 'dbo.Settings' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index."
I'll be looking into this myself but any thoughts?

Comment: @KiraNamida yes, it's probably a `nvarchar(max)`. And `nvarchar(max)` is not accepted for indexes... You have to put a lower value (like `nvarchar(128)` for example.

Comment: Keeping this up to date. Solved that one by setting the string max length to 450 (max number of characters that equal the max number of bytes available). NOw moving on to solving: ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Name failed because one or more objects access this column.

Comment: Update: This seems to be because of an existing constraint on the table that affects this column. Now to track it down and make sure it is removed.

Comment: @KiraNamida in You we trust, you're on the way !

Comment: I found the constraint, worked around it and now the database is throwing the exception I'm expecting when I break the constraint. Thanks for you advice, it got me where I needed to be. =3