# How do you deal with race between two client upserts?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, concurrency

I'm writing a simple messaging module so one process can publish messages and another can subscribe to them.  I'm using EF/SqlServer as the out of process communication mechanism.  A "Server" is just a name that a publisher/subscriber pair have in common (could have been called a "Channel").

I have the following method which adds a row to the database representing a named "Server"

```
    public void AddServer(string name)
    {
        if (!context.Servers.Any(c => c.Name == name))
        {
            context.Servers.Add(new Server { Name = name });
        }
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that when I start two clients at the same time, only one is supposed to add a new Server entry, however, that is not how it's working out.  I'm actually getting the very wrong result of two entries with the same name, and realizing that an Any() guard is not sufficient for this.

The Entity for Server uses an int PK and supposedly my repository would enforce the uniqueness of the Name field.  I'm starting to think this isn't going to work though.

```
public class Server
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The two ways I think I could fix this both seem less than ideal:

1. String primary keys
2. Ignoring Exception

This is the issue of concurrency, right?

How can I deal with it in this situation where I want two clients to call the repository with the same Name but get a result of only one row with that name in the database?

[image]

**Update**: Here is the Repository Code

```
namespace MyBus.Data
{
    public class Repository : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly Context context;
        private readonly bool autoSave;

        public delegate Chain Chain(Action<Repository> action);
        public static Chain Command(Action<Repository> action)
        {
            using (var repo = new Data.Repository(true))
            {
                action(repo);
            }
            return new Chain(next => Command(next));
        }

        public Repository(bool autoSave)
        {
            this.autoSave = autoSave;
            context = new Context();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (autoSave)
                context.SaveChanges();
            context.Dispose();
        }

        public void AddServer(string name)
        {
            if (!context.Servers.Any(c => c.Name == name))
            {
                context.Servers.Add(new Server { Name = name });
            }
        }

        public void AddClient(string name, bool isPublisher)
        {
            if (!context.Clients.Any(c => c.Name == name))
            {
                context.Clients.Add(new Client
                {
                    Name = name,
                    ClientType = isPublisher ? ClientType.Publisher : ClientType.Subscriber
                });
            }
        }

        public void AddMessageType<T>()
        {
            var typeName = typeof(T).FullName;
            if (!context.MessageTypes.Any(c => c.Name == typeName))
            {
                context.MessageTypes.Add(new MessageType { Name = typeName });
            }
        }

        public void AddRegistration<T>(string serverName, string clientName)
        {
            var server = context.Servers.Single(c => c.Name == serverName);
            var client = context.Clients.Single(c => c.Name == clientName);
            var messageType = context.MessageTypes.Single(c => c.Name == typeof(T).FullName);
            if (!context.Registrations.Any(c =>
                    c.ServerId == server.Id &&
                    c.ClientId == client.Id &&
                    c.MessageTypeId == messageType.Id))
            {
                context.Registrations.Add(new Registration
                {
                    Client = client,
                    Server = server,
                    MessageType = messageType
                });
            }
        }

        public void AddMessage<T>(T item, out int messageId)
        {
            var messageType = context.MessageTypes.Single(c => c.Name == typeof(T).FullName);
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (var sw = new StringWriter(sb))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(sw, item);
            }
            var message = new Message
            {
                MessageType = messageType,
                Created = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Data = sb.ToString()
            };
            context.Messages.Add(message);
            context.SaveChanges();
            messageId = message.Id;
        }

        public void CreateDeliveries<T>(int messageId, string serverName, string sendingClientName, T item)
        {
            var messageType = typeof(T).FullName;

            var query = from reg in context.Registrations
                        where reg.Server.Name == serverName &&
                              reg.Client.ClientType == ClientType.Subscriber &&
                              reg.MessageType.Name == messageType
                        select new
                        {
                            reg.ClientId
                        };

            var senderClientId = context.Clients.Single(c => c.Name == sendingClientName).Id;

            foreach (var reg in query)
            {
                context.Deliveries.Add(new Delivery
                {
                    SenderClientId = senderClientId,
                    ReceiverClientId = reg.ClientId,
                    MessageId = messageId,
                    Updated = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    DeliveryStatus = DeliveryStatus.Sent
                });
            }
        }

        public List<T> GetDeliveries<T>(string serverName, string clientName, out List<int> messageIds)
        {
            messageIds = new List<int>();
            var messages = new List<T>();
            var clientId = context.Clients.Single(c => c.Name == clientName).Id;
            var query = from del in context.Deliveries
                        where del.ReceiverClientId == clientId &&
                              del.DeliveryStatus == DeliveryStatus.Sent
                        select new
                        {
                            del.Id,
                            del.Message.Data
                        };
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                using (var sr = new StringReader(item.Data))
                {
                    var t = (T)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
                    messages.Add(t);
                    messageIds.Add(item.Id);
                }
            }
            return messages;
        }

        public void ConfirmDelivery(int deliveryId)
        {
            using (var context = new Context())
            {
                context.Deliveries.First(c => c.Id == deliveryId).DeliveryStatus = DeliveryStatus.Received;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use a transaction.

Comment: Are your two clients re-using the same instance of `context`?

Comment: no they are two separate processes..

Comment: Who do you want to win the race? First or last? This affects what solution is best.

Comment: In my case, the two clients are both saying "I am using server X" and the first one that tells the system about it causes the system to insert a row, so I think I'm saying it doesn't matter - if I understand you correctly

Comment: Can you include more of your code? Just calling `context.Add()` is not a race condition until `context.SaveChanges()` is called.

Comment: sure, i pasted in the repository

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the int primary key, but also define a [unique index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175132%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on the `Name` column.

This way, in concurrency situations only the first insert would be successful; any subsequent clients that attempt to insert the same server name would fail with an `SqlException`.

Comment: i'm thinking of resorting to manual TSQL - I just need an insert query  that only inserts if matching row doesn't already..

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using this solution:

```
    public void AddServer(string name)
    {
        if (!context.Servers.Any(c => c.Name == name))
        {
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"MERGE Servers WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS T
                                                 USING (SELECT {0} AS Name) AS S
                                                 ON T.Name = S.Name
                                                 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
                                                 INSERT (Name) VALUES ({0});", name);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As an exercise in thoroughness I (think I) solved this problem another way, which preserves the type safety of the EF context but adds a bit of complexity:

First, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413084/unique-constraint-in-entity-framework-code-first), I learned how to add a unique constraint to the Server table:

Here's the Context code:

```
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<MessageType> MessageTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Delivery> Deliveries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Server> Servers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Registration> Registrations { get; set; }

        public class Initializer : IDatabaseInitializer<Context>
        {
            public void InitializeDatabase(Context context)
            {
                if (context.Database.Exists() && !context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(false))
                    context.Database.Delete();

                if (!context.Database.Exists())
                {
                    context.Database.Create();
                    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                       @"alter table Servers 
                         add constraint UniqueServerName unique (Name)");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I need a way to selectively ignore exception when saving.  I did this by adding the following members to my repository:

```
readonly List<Func<Exception, bool>> ExceptionsIgnoredOnSave = 
    new List<Func<Exception, bool>>();

static readonly Func<Exception, bool> UniqueConstraintViolation =
    e => e.AnyMessageContains("Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint");
```

Along with a new extension method to loop keep from depending on the position of the text in the inner exception chain:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static bool AnyMessageContains(this Exception ex, string text)
    {
        while (ex != null)
        {
            if(ex.Message.Contains(text))
                return true;
            ex = ex.InnerException;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And I modified the Dispose method of my Repository to check if the exception should be ignored or re-thrown:

```
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (autoSave)
        {
            try
            {
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {      
                if(!ExceptionsIgnoredOnSave.Any(pass => pass(ex)))
                    throw;
                Console.WriteLine("ignoring exception..."); // temp
            }
        }
        context.Dispose();
    }
```

Finally, in the method which invokes the `Add`, I add the acceptable condition to the list:

```
    public void AddServer(string name)
    {
        ExceptionsIgnoredOnSave.Add(UniqueConstraintViolation);

        if (!context.Servers.Any(c => c.Name == name))
        {
            var server = context.Servers.Add(new Server { Name = name });
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 I recommend you match on the SqlException.Number though. Your code breaks in other locales and future releases of SQL Server.