# What does it mean to make my username unique at database level?

Tags: sql, database, unique

Hey guys. I have a quick question to understand what this means for my project.  I am supposed to have my usernames be unique (and enforced at a database level).  What does this mean when referring to database level?  I am using ASP.net MVC5 with SQL Express as my database.

Comment: Create a `unique constraint` on the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to make certain only unique names are in the database, so you can look at this for more

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f7ded633-5d66-4cda-a525-96ab97cee868/sqlexpress-create-unique-column

Basically do

```
Alter table users add constraint uniq_user unique(username)
```

Comment: Awesome thank you for ansewer, just added it to my t-sql view.  It popped up under my keys saying UNQ_UserName (UserName), but it doesnt say unique key around it.  Is that ok?

Comment: We are using codefirst methods that generate the database, is the any way I can add that constraint to a model?

Comment: I expect it won't work, but test and see if you get an error when inserting a duplicate username

Comment: You may want to see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413084/unique-constraint-in-entity-framework-code-first