# unique constraint on model property using code first approach?

Tags: c#, .net, entity, code-first

If I have class

```
public class Hotel
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

how can set unique constraint on Name property using code first approach?

Comment: Try this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701608/unique-key-with-ef-code-first See the edit on the answer for EF6.1 solution.

Comment: For a question specifically on unique constraint (not unique index), see http://stackoverflow.com/q/4413084/1149773