# How do I establish a one to one relationship with Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity

I've been reading all the Google and SO pages about people who are establishing a one to one relationship in `EF` but it just isn't working for me.

Here is my model:

Account:

```
public int Id {get; set;}
public virtual AccountConfig AccountConfig {get; set;}
```

Account Map:

```
HasKey(t => t.Id);
HasRequired(t => t.AccountConfig)
    .WithOptional();
```

Account Config:

```
public int Id {get; set;}
public int AccountId {get; set;}
public virtual Account Account {get; set;}
```

Account Config Map:

```
HasKey(t => t.Id);
HasRequired(t => t.Account)
    .WithOptional(t => t.AccountConfig);
```

When executed, the `AccountConfig` property on `Account` is `NULL` and the `Account` property on `AccountConfig` is an incorrect record (coincidentally, the retrieved `Account.Id` is the same as the `AccountConfig.Id`, but I don't know if that means anything).

In the database, the `Account` table doesn't have a reference to the `AccountConfig` record but the `AccountConfig` table has a reference to the `Account` record using the `AccountId` column.

The end result would be for me to have a reference to the `AccountConfig` from `Account` and (if possible), a reference to `Account` from `AccountConfig`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With EF, one-to-one relationships are only supported on tables that share a primary key.  Your `AccountConfig` table has its own primary key, and a foreign key to `Account`.  EF only supports a one-to-many relationship with this configuration.

[This article](http://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2011/06/02/entity-framework-4-1-one-to-one-mapping/) has a nice explanation of 1:1 and 1:0..1 relationships in EF.  The restriction here is a by-product of the fact that [EF doesn't yet support unique constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11819804/439024).

Comment: So I'd only be able to reference the AccountConfig table from Account if the Account table has a column called AccountConfigId?

Comment: Not exactly.  Your `AccountConfig` entity should have only an `Id` column; remove the `AccountId` column and ensure that `Id` is not auto-generated.  When adding `AccountConfig` entities, their `Id`s should explicitly be set to be the same as the `Id` of the `Account` table record.

Comment: See the article I've linked for an example that's quite similar to yours.

Comment: If I would have found this answer 5 hours ago, I would have saved myself 5 hours. *shaking my head*