# How to make One-To-One relationship with existing fields?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5

I have 3 entities:

- `Foo`
- `Bar`
- `UniqueFooBar`

`Foo` and `Bar` are entities as follows:

```
public class Bar {

   public int Id {get; set;}

   // inverse nav property
   public virtual UniqueFooBar UniqueFooBar {get; set;}

}

public class Foo {

   public string Name {get; set;}

   // inverse nav property
   public virtual UniqueFooBar UniqueFooBar {get; set;}
}
```

And `UniqueFooBar` is a lookup as follows:

```
public class UniqueFooBar {

   public string FooName {get; set;}
   public int BarId {get; set;}

   // nav properties
   public virtual Foo Foo {get; set;}
   public virtual Bar Bar {get; set;}

}
```

With constraints that:

- `Foo` is unique
- there is a one-to-one relationship to both `Foo` and `Bar`
- `Foo` Name is the PK

  The fluent API is as follows:

  ```
  class UniqueFooBarConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<UniqueFooBar> {
      public UniqueFooBarConfiguration() {
          // Define the tablename and schema
          Map(entity => entity.ToTable("UniqueFooBars"));

          //// Define non-conventional key
          HasKey(fooBar => fooBar.FooName);

          // Define FKs -  1-to-1
          HasRequired(fooBar => fooBar.Foo)
              .WithRequiredPrincipal(foo => foo.UniqueFooBar)
              .Map(key => key.MapKey("FooName"));
          HasRequired(fooBar => fooBar.Bar)
              .WithRequiredPrincipal(bar => bar.UniqueFooBar)
              .Map(key => key.MapKey("BarId"));
          // --------------------------------

      }

  }
  ```

What is happening is that `FooName` is being added to the Foo table **and** `BarId` is being added tot he Bar table.

If, in the fluent API configuration for `UniqueFooBar`, I instead try to use Foo's "Name" property then there is an error that the field already exists. Same happens if I try to use Bar's "Id" property.

How can I configure UniqueFooBar to have FKs to `Foo.Name` and `Bar.Id` as one-to-one relationships?

**Update**

- Neither `Foo` nor `Bar` has constraint or requirement of a `UniqueFooBar`.
- A UniqueFooBar record requires a `FooName` and a `BarId`

This does not appear to be the same as [How to declare one to one relationship using Entity Framework 4 Code First (POCO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622572/how-to-declare-one-to-one-relationship-using-entity-framework-4-code-first-poco)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to declare one to one relationship using Entity Framework 4 Code First (POCO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622572/how-to-declare-one-to-one-relationship-using-entity-framework-4-code-first-poco)

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549680/how-do-i-establish-a-one-to-one-relationship-with-entity-framework-code-first ?

Comment: @PaulZahra if you can summarize the link in that accepted answer, then I'll accept it: http://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2011/06/02/entity-framework-4-1-one-to-one-mapping/  
Because a bounty is attached, a bit of summary would be nice with replication of the relevant code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [here](http://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2011/06/02/entity-framework-4-1-one-to-one-mapping/), below is an example of how you can achieve one to one mapping between two entities, extrapolate this for a link table, adding HasRequired as required.

It is possible to specify WithRequiredPrincipal without a lambda, which allows you to exclude a navigation property and still get a proper one to one mapping.

Within an override of the OnModelCreating method you define your relationships by using the DBModelBuilder parameter.

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        Address = new Address();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}

public  class  CustomerContext : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .HasRequired(x => x.Address)
                .WithRequiredPrincipal();
         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra bit of explanation ... I think I understand why *things just didn't work* before. If I understand correctly, because I have a forward nav property, I don't need to supply a lambda in the `WithRequiredPrincipal` method; this is where there seems to be some confusion.