# Unique constraint entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

I'm using MS SQL Server 2012 + the Entity Framework 6.1.1. I have created a model using the designer. Now, I would like to add a unique to an attribute. How can I achieve this using the designer / keep the model generation?

Edit: I do the model first approach

Thank you

Comment: Model first? Or database first?

Answer (score 1):

[Read this!](http://www.geethanga.com/2013/11/adding-unique-constraints-entity.html) It should help you in the right direction...

The idea is to use code like this:

```
CreateIndex("dbo.Users","Username",true);
```

Which is a EF method. I don't think it's possible in the designer then...

**EDIT**

Found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819674/does-entity-framework-5-support-unique-constraints) that states that unique constraints are possible (not in the designer, but in code) like this:

```
[Index(IsUnique = true)]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

Comment: So not in model first. `[Index(IsUnique = true)]` is code first, from EF 6.1.